# Does CORS interact with WebAssembly the same way it does with Javascript?

Tags: cors, web-assembly

Anyone in the WebAppSec world is familiar with CORS as a mechanism to specify policy for when javascript is allowed to make API calls to different domains. As WebAssembly ("Wasm" - a binary web language standardized in 2019; [webassembly.org](https://webassembly.org/), [wikipedia/WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly)) gains popularity, I'm curious if my CORS:Javascript knowledge transfers over cleanly to CORS:Wasm, or if CORS has different behaviour and "gotchas" with Wasm?

For example, from the Mozilla docs:

- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) mentions javascript a bunch of times, but not Wasm.
- From the docs, it seems like CORS applies to the browser APIs [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), and I'm not expert enough to know if those are javascript APIs and I need to go looking in Wasm API docs for the Wasm equivalents, or if those APIs are low-level enough that they are common to JS and Wasm and therefore Wasm inherits exactly the CORS that I know and love.

Comment: Interesting question, +1.  One minor nitpick:  `'CORS as a mechanism to restrict javascript from making calls to different domains'` - actually, Same Origin Policy (SOP) is what restricts restrict javascript from making calls to different domains.  CORS is used to relax SOP, in cases where cross-origin requests are allowed.

Comment: @mti2935 Good nit, thanks. Is this better? `a mechanism to specify policy for when javascript is allowed to make API calls to different domains` ?

Comment: That looks better.  I'm in the process now of trying to cook up a quick wasm module to do a cross-origin request as a test to see if (a) the request is blocked by SOP (as it should be), then if so, (b) if the request is allowed once a CORS policy is put in place to relax SOP.  Stand by...

Comment: @mti2935 Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Same-Origin Policy (SOP) applies to web assembly modules.  See https://webassembly.org/docs/security/, where it states:

> Additionally, each module is subject to the security policies of its embedding. Within a web browser, this includes restrictions on information flow through same-origin policy.